# Preprocessing Sklearn Imputer when column missing values

Tags: python, scikit-learn, preprocessor

I'm trying to use Imputer for missing values.
I would like to keep track also of columns with all missing values but because otherwise I don't know which of them (columns) have been processed:
Is possible to return also columns with all missing values?

> Impute Notes
>
> When axis=0, columns which only contained missing values at fit are
> discarded upon transform. When axis=1, an exception is raised if there
> are rows for which it is not possible to fill in the missing values
> (e.g., because they only contain missing values).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
data={'b1':[1,2,3,4,5],'b2':[1,2,4,4,0],'b3':[0,0,0,0,0]}
X= pd.DataFrame(data)
Imp = Imputer(missing_values=0)
print (Imp.fit_transform(X))

print(X)
   b1  b2  b3
0   1   1   0
1   2   2   0
2   3   4   0
3   4   4   0
4   5   0   0

runfile
[[ 1.    1.  ]
 [ 2.    2.  ]
 [ 3.    4.  ]
 [ 4.    4.  ]
 [ 5.    2.75]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `statistics_` attribute from the [`Imputer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html) class will return the fill value for each column, including the dropped ones.

> **statistics_** : array of shape (n_features,)
>   The imputation fill value for each feature if axis == 0.

```
Imp.statistics_
array([3.  , 2.75,  nan])
```

An example of getting column names of the columns with all "missing" values.

```
nanmask = np.isnan(Imp.statistics_)

nanmask
array([False, False,  True])

X.columns[nanmask]
Index([u'b3'], dtype='object')
```